# Spring Boot Couchbase Repository throws error 5001 during query

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am using **Springboot 2.1.4** with *spring-boot-data-couchbase*. I am trying to make a *paginated query* using like operator for one property.

These are the artifacts:

- Repository

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "LogicalResource", viewName = "all")
public interface LogicalResourceRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<LogicalResource, String>
{
    Page<LogicalResource> findByValueLike(String value, Pageable pageable);    
}
```

- Service

```
@Service
public class LogicalResourceService extends BaseCrudService<LogicalResource> 
{

    @Autowired
    LogicalResourceRepository logicalResourceRepository;

    @Override
    public EntityListSlice<LogicalResource> simpleSearch(Integer page, Integer size, String search) 
    {   
        Page<LogicalResource> pageData = this.logicalResourceRepository.findByValueLike("%"+search+"%", PageRequest.of(page, size));

        long totalElements = pageData.getTotalElements();
        List<LogicalResource> data = pageData.getContent();

        return new EntityListSlice<LogicalResource>()
                .setPage(page)
                .setSize(size)
                .setTotal(totalElements)
                .setEntities(data);
    }

}
```

The class EntityListSlice is just a pojo to handle the data.

When the mehthod is invoked, the follow exception is thrown:

**Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors: ↵{"msg":"Panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference","code":5001}**

¿Is there a better way to make this kind of queries? ¿How can I handle the exception?

Comment: Hi! I'm not familiar with this error, can you post your entity? Nothing seems wrong with your code at first, the only issue is that "value" is a reserved word, so I guess that is the error.

Comment: I think the error is about the property called "value" about you said. I made a test with another property and everything is ok.  ¿Is there another way to make the query? ¿Do you need to see the entity?

Comment: No worries, as long as you have solved the problem, that is ok.